# How to send messages to my JMS queue WebLogic server from my Spring Java application

Tags: java, jms, weblogic12c, spring-jms

I have one module with several queues in my WebLogic, and I need to send data to one specific queue from a Java application which I already developed. However, I don't have any idea where do I find the port of each queue or how I make that my Spring application point to the specific queue. My Spring application is using these values (local). So I guess I just need to find the port. Which I could not so far.

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=admin
spring.profiles.active=prod
```

I looked up in my queue, all the different options in WebLogic such as (Configuring, Monitoring, Control, Security, etc...) and still don't find anything useful same in Oracle's documentation.

Comment: Why are you using ActiveMQ properties to work with WebLogic?

Comment: What do you mean by the "port" of the queue? Are you talking about a TCP port where the server is listening for network connections?

Comment: When you need to send a mail you should have a recipient. The same in software development. If you need to send a message in a certain place then you need to point this place out. Java and Spring cannot decide where to send instead of you.